# Undefined index: cck_time_field_presave()

Tags: datetime

I have imported about 2 thousand nodes that include start time.

I have imported and the formating and time looks the way it should.

Now if i try to publish the nodes i get following error -

> Notice: Undefined index: hour in cck_time_field_presave() (line 97 of
>   public_html/sites/all/modules/cck_time/cck_time.module).

The time fields gets changed to null time.

But if I open the node and save it - the node is saved with the correct time as it was before.

Im at a loss.

And hoping for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to CCK Time then open cck_time.module

find this:

```
function cck_time_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items)
```

change this:

```
if (($items[0]['hour'] === '') || ($items[0]['minute'] === ''))
```

to this:

```
if ( empty($items[0]['hour']) || empty($items[0]['minute']) )
```

It helped solving my problem getting the same error **Undefined index: cck_time_field_presave()**